# jQuery click event to display specific data inside JSON array not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have created 3 dummy users with JSON array like this:

```
var userArray = {"users":[
    {"Name":"User1","Email":"user1@something.com"},
    {"Name":"User2","Email":"user2@something.com"},
    {"Name":"User3","Email":"user3@something.com"}
]};
```

Now, I want to display only the name of each user stored inside a div that has a class.

```
var i = 0
document.writeln("<div id=tableThis>");
for(i=0;i<userArray.users.length;i++)
{
    document.writeln("<div class=allUser>");
    document.writeln("<b>User :: </b>"
            + userArray.users[i].Name);
    document.writeln("<div class=emails><b>Email :: </b>"
            + userArray.users[i].Email  +"</div>");
    document.writeln("</div>");
}
```

It works fine to display only the names if I give the class `.emails` `display:none`

Now, what I am trying to achieve is when each name is clicked, it should display their e-mails below in a div.
But everytime I click the div called `.allUser` it will display all the emails right away, which makes sense because all of the emails have the same class.

I am using the code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".allUser").click(function() {
    $('.emails').show(1000);
});
```

});

I would preferably want to toggle each name so I could show, hide each users email when you click the name of each user.

It´s hard for me to provide a fiddle when they dont allow `document.writeIn`

Would there be a neater/cleaner way to achieve this small task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [**deleagted event**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as html is generated dynamically after DOM load, and use [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get Child element with class **.emails**,

Do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click",".allUser",function() {
    $(this),find('.emails').show(1000);
});

});
```